# Test a method which calls another method of the object in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have an interface, ex:

```
interface MyService {
  void createObj(int id)
  void createObjects()
}
```

I want to test an implementation of the `createObjects` method, which has body like:

```
void createObjects() {
  ...
  for (...) {
     createObj(someId);
  }
}
```

I have already tested `createObj(id)`:

```
@Test public void testCreate() {
  //given
  int id = 123;
  DAO mock = mock(DAO.class);
  MyService service = new MyServiceImpl(mock);

  //when
  service.createObj(id);

  //verify
  verify(mock).create(eq(id));
}
```

So I don't want to repeat all test cases for it in the test for `createObjects`.

How can I make sure that another method of the real object was called besides the one I am testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a spy:

```
MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl()
MyService spy = spy(myService);
doNothing().when(spy).createObj(anyInt());

// now call spy.createObjects() and verify that spy.createObj() has been called
```

This is described, like everything else, in [the api doc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy).

Comment: Thank you. I am using exactly this. But docs say that this can "smell", so I am thinking about why is it so and how to avoid that :)

Comment: This is exactly what spies are for.  "Smell" doesn't necessarily mean that something is wrong; only that something **might be** wrong.  In this particular case, this is the right thing to do.